# Load text file into an array in Swift

Tags: array, file, error-handling, swift

I'm drowning in Swift optionals and error handling syntax. I'm just converting a text file into an array of Strings. One would think that this could be a simple two or three liner but by the time I got it to work, I ended up with the following mess:

```
enum ImportError: ErrorType {
    case FileNotFound
    case CouldntGetArray
}

private func getLineArrayFromFile(fileName: String) throws -> Array<String> {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)
    if path == nil {
        throw ImportError.FileNotFound
    }

    var lineArray: Array<String>?
    do {

        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        lineArray = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

    }catch{
        throw ImportError.CouldntGetArray
    }

    return lineArray!
}
```

I actually don't really care about the using `ErrorType` enum, but I wanted to play around with the new Swift [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) syntax.

I thought I understood optionals before, but they were giving me a headache when combined with the `do-try-catch` statement. I also didn't know if I should return an Array or an Optional Array.

What are the best practices for a situation like this?

- Error handling
- Treatment of optionals
- Code brevity/readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> func getLineArrayFromFile(fileName: String) throws -> Array<String>
> ```

- The function does not get lines from an arbitrary file, but from a *resource file*.
- The "get" prefix is usually not used in Objective-C or Swift.
- `Array<String>` can be shortened to `[String]`.

So my suggestion for the function name would be

```
func linesFromResource(fileName: String) throws -> [String]
```

> ```
> let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)
> if path == nil {
>     throw ImportError.FileNotFound
> }
> ```

- As you are obviously using Swift 2, this can be simplified with the `guard` 
  statement. Note that `path` is no longer an optional.
- There are pre-defined `NSError` codes which can be used here instead of
  defining your own. This also gives better error descriptions for free.

Example:

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil) else {
    throw NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSFileNoSuchFileError, userInfo: [ NSFilePathErrorKey : fileName ])
}
```

> ```
> do {
>     let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
>     lineArray = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
> } catch {
>     throw ImportError.CouldntGetArray
> }
> ```

You are catching the error and throw your own error code in the failure case,
so the actual error information is lost.
Better just call the `try String(..)` and let an error propagate to the
caller of your function:

```
let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Again, this gives better error descriptions for free.

So the complete method would now look like this (no optionals anymore,
no forced unwrapping with `!`):

```
func linesFromResource(fileName: String) throws -> [String] {

    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil) else {
        throw NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSFileNoSuchFileError, userInfo: [ NSFilePathErrorKey : fileName ])
    }
    let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
}
```

And a typical usage would be

```
do {
    let lines = try linesFromResource("file.txt")
    print(lines)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

The reason for the final `catch let error` is that it is required that the `catch` statements are exhaustive.
Even if *we* know that the function throws only `NSError`s, the compiler doesn't know
that. (There are exceptions but that is a different topic .)

Now to your question how an error should be handled in general, and I would 
say: it depends. There are tree different scenarios:

- Loading the strings can fail, and you want to present or log an error message
  in that case. Then the above method of throwing and catching an error is appropriate.
- Loading the strings can fail, but the particular reason is of no interest
  to the caller. In that case I would change the function to return an optional.

Example:

```
func linesFromResource(fileName: String) -> [String]? {

    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil) else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

 // Usage:
if let lines = linesFromResource("file.txt") {
    print(lines)
}
```

- Finally, if failing to load the strings is a *programming error* then the function should *abort* in
  the error case, and return the (non-optional) strings otherwise.

As an example, if this function is only used to load strings from fixed compiled-in
resource files which are supposed to exist, then failing to load a file would
be a programming error and should be detected early:

```
func linesFromResource(fileName: String) -> [String] {

    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil) else {
        fatalError("Resource file for \(fileName) not found.")
    }
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Could not load strings from \(path): \(error).")
    }
}

let lines = linesFromResource("file.txt")
print(lines)
```

`fatalError()` prints a message before stopping execution of the program, which can
be helpful to locate the programming error. Otherwise you could shorten the
"forced" version to

```
func linesFromResourceForced(fileName: String) -> [String] {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)!
    let content = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
}
```

which is the "three liner" that you were looking for in the introduction to
your question.

Comment: My main learning points from your answer: (1) avoid the non-standard "get" naming prefix, (2) use the predefined error codes when available rather than making my own, (3) let the error propagate to the caller, (4) when to use different error handling methods: (a) need message--throw/catch, (b) don't need message--optional, (c) programming error--abort immediately. You taught me a lot. Thank you very much for taking the time to do this!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)
> if path == nil {
>     throw ImportError.FileNotFound
> }
> ```

We can clean this part up into a `guard let`, which not only saves us a line, but also has the advantage of making `path` a non-optional.

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType:nil) {
    throw ImportError.FileNotFound
}
```

If `path` would be `nil`, we enter the `guard` block and throw.  Otherwise, we can treat `path` as a non-optional.

---

In fact, we can apply the `guard let` all the way through your method.

```
guard let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    throw ImportError.CouldNotLoadFile
}

let newLineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lineArray = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newLineChars).filter({!isEmpty($0)})

return lineArray
```

Note that I've got a different error and it's more accurate.  Splitting a string into components either by a string or by a character set cannot return `nil`, nor can it throw any sort of an error.

Importantly though, I'm splitting the string on the `newLineCharacterSet()` rather than just the `'\n'` character.  This will give us more accurate results regardless of what platform the file was created on.

Comment: Sorry for "duplicating" the `guard let path = NSBundle ...` part, but I had prepared that already. Your `guard let content = try String ...` statement seems not to compile though.

Comment: @nhgrif, I had seen the `guard` keyword before but I didn't really understand how it was used until I read your answer. That was helpful.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken,  you cannot use `guard` to catch the error from a `throw`.